# How can I describe this domain?

Tags: soft-question, definition

I solved an equation on a 3D-domain which is *the unitary sphere where a torus has been removed*.

How can I describe it with proper mathematical words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solid sphere is given by $S(x,y,z)\le0$ and the solid torus is given by $T(x,y,z)\le0$, then your region is given by $S(x,y,z)\le0, T(x,y,z)\ge0$.

A parametric representation of the boundary of your region depends on the size and location of the torus and is bound to be complicated because there are many cases to consider. See [this paper](http://bh.knu.ac.kr/%7Ekujinkim/papers/s_tsi.pdf) for instance.

Comment: I think it's the opposite of what you wrote: from the unit 3d ball, a the torus (of smallest radii) has been removed

Comment: @andereBen, $T(x,y,z)\ge0$ gives the exterior of the torus.

Comment: You're right :)